# Python 3.4.3 - Windows7 64 - install win32com error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running a Windows 7 64bit machine.  I installed Python 3.4.3 32 bit. I've been using in with various libs and no problem.

I now needed to load wincom32. 
I to get pywin32-219win-amd64-py3.4.exe
When I run the exe install, it told me I didnt have version 3.4: 
("Python version 3.4 required ,which was not found in the registry")

Due diligence on the web found that it could be a Python wrong 32 vs 64 bit - when Python Idle starts, it says I'm running:
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

I looked for articles on registry settings and in examining the registry, I dont have Python listed in anything except classes.

Someone mentioned to copy the pywintypes32.dll - but I dont have that file.

So do I need to uninstall and install a different Python version?
If so, what version should I install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [pywin32-219.win32-py3.4.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.win32-py3.4.exe/download) as your Python is 32-bit, not x64. The library version should match your Python installation, not your Windows installation. You can have both Python 32-bit and x64 installed on the same computer, each with its own libraries.